# QGIS Server working well on local VM but remote server config fail

Tags: qgis-server, apache

Trying to understand how to setup QGIS Server I started on a local Ubuntu VM. After a day of debuging I got something that's work.

I try to replicate the same on my hosted VM (GCP). I got the classical  :

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.3.0">
  <ServiceException code="Service configuration error">Service unknown or unsupported</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

When I hit the server IP + `cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi`. So QGIS Server itself work.

But when I try to get the capabilities I got a 500 error, which lead me to server issue more than QGIS Server.

`/cgi-bin/qgismapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilitie`

Here the VirtualHost that I have.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin my@email
  ServerName qgis.test # -> I have binded the ip and the name to my /etc/hosts the time I have a real URL to add to my DNS.

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  # Apache logs (different than QGIS Server log)
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/qgis.demo.error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/qgis.demo.access.log combined

  # Longer timeout for WPS... default = 40
  FcgidIOTimeout 120

  FcgidInitialEnv LC_ALL "en_US.UTF-8"
  FcgidInitialEnv PYTHONIOENCODING UTF-8
  FcgidInitialEnv LANG "en_US.UTF-8"

  # QGIS log (different from apache logs) see https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html#qgis-server-logging
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_FILE /var/log/qgis/qgisserver.log
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL 0

  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_DEBUG 1

  # default QGIS project
  SetEnv QGIS_PROJECT_FILE /home/sysadm/01_General_test.qgs

  # QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH must lead to a directory writeable by the Server's FCGI process user
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH "/home/sysadm/qgisserverdb/"
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_AUTH_PASSWORD_FILE "/home/sysadm/qgisserverdb/qgis-auth.db"

  # See https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#pg-service-file
  SetEnv PGSERVICEFILE /home/sysadm/.pg_service.conf
  FcgidInitialEnv PGPASSFILE "/home/sysadm/.pgpass"

  # Tell QGIS Server instances to use a specific display number
  FcgidInitialEnv DISPLAY ":99"

  # if qgis-server is installed from packages in debian based distros this is usually /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  # run "locate qgis_mapserv.fcgi" if you don't know where qgis_mapserv.fcgi is
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

 <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
   FcgidMaxRequestLen 26214400
   FcgidConnectTimeout 60
 </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea ?